# Apache mod_wsgi 32-bit/64-bit Python compatibility

Tags: python, django, apache

I use Zend Studio / Zend Server for developing my PHP-based web sites, but now I'm taking a course in Python, and I want to learn Django.

I have a Windows 7 AMD-64 machine, and am using 64-bit Python 2.6 (version 2.6 is required by the course), and that part works fine.

My problem is trying to add mod_wsgi to my Zend Server's 32-bit Apache installation.  I've downloaded several versions of mod_wsgi 32-bit Windows binaries for Python 2.6, and copied them to C:Program Files (x86)\Zend\Apache2\modules directory, edited httpd.conf and added:

LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so

restarted Apached2.2-Zend, and then tested if mod_wsgi was loaded at the command prompt with:

httpd -t -M

However, mod_wsgi does not show up on the list of loaded modules.

I finally figured this might not be working because I cannot mix-and-match 64-bit Python 2.6 with 32-bit ZendServer Apache2.2.

So here's the meat of my question:

Can I install a 64-bit version of Apache 2.2 and run that at the same time as ZendServer Apache2.2 (but configure the 64-bit version so it doesn't listen on the same ports as my ZendSever Apache2.2) so all my local PHP virtual hosts still work?  Maybe I would have better luck getting mod_wsgi to load with this Apache?

Or, would it be better to install a 32-bit version of Python (probably a higher version like Python 2.8, since I only need Python 2.6 for my coursework, and I am trying to get Django working just for my own web site development)?  Would that allow my ZendServer Apache2.2 to load mod_wsgi?  Also, how does Apache figure out which installation of Python it should be using if I have both on my Windows 7 machine?

Comment: I would just install the 32-bit version of 2.7.5 and use that. It'll just be easier to work with, as you won't have to mess with two versions of Apache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I install a 64-bit version of Apache 2.2 and run that at the same time as ZendServer Apache2.2 (but configure the 64-bit version so it doesn't listen on the same ports as my ZendSever Apache2.2)

Yes, you can.

You've already thought about the hardest problem: that it can't listen on the same ports.

A related problem is that some people's networks don't allow them to make outgoing connections to, say, port 8080; if you want to deal with that, you'll need to set up your ZendServer to act as a forward proxy for the other server. But that's really about it.

The only other problem is that you need to make sure your two copies of Apache don't try to share the same config files, etc. (and you may not want both of them on your PATH, either).

---

> Or, would it be better to install a 32-bit version of Python (probably a higher version like Python 2.8

There is no 2.8, and never will be. The last 2.x version is 2.7 (although it continues to get bug fixes, and is up to 2.7.5). If you want something higher, you have to go to 3.x. If everything you need runs on 3.3 (and Django 1.5+ does), and you're willing to learn the small changes, you should consider this. But if you want to stick with what you already know, get 2.7.5.

> Would that allow my ZendServer Apache2.2 to load mod_wsgi?

Well, not if you're using a `mod_wsgi` for Python 2.6 and install a Python 2.7 or 3.3… or using a `mod_wsgi` for native Python and install a Cygwin Python… etc. But I suspect you already know that (given "I've downloaded several versions of mod_wsgi 32-bit Windows binaries for Python 2.6").

Other than that, yes. As long as everything is built and configured right, it will work. (I have no idea what particular packages you downloaded and installed, so I can't promise whether they will work, of course.)

> Also, how does Apache figure out which installation of Python it should be using if I have both on my Windows 7 machine?

This is configurable. I believe the default is to use either whatever it finds first on your `PATH`, or whatever shows up as the "default python 2.x" in your registry settings, as used by the Python command-line launcher described in [PEP 397](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0397/). (And of course if that Python is not the one it was built against, it will fail to start up.)

Comment: The mod_wsgi binary is compiled for a specific version of Python. If the Python installations are different versions, it will only use (and can only use), the one it was compiled for.

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton: Yes, I thought that was already obvious to the OP, given his question ("I've downloaded several versions of mod_wsgi 32-bit Windows binaries for Python 2.6"). But if you think I need to clarify that, I'll edit it.

Comment: I clarified it because your comment 'This is configurable' in part suggested that Apache/mod_wsgi could be made to select a different Python version. You appear to have clarified that since I commented.

Comment: Wow - thank you all for all the quick responses - I'm overwhelmed (in a good way!) I've found a bunch of answers on stackoverflow before, but this was the first question I had the courage to ask.  (I feel especially honored that Graham Dumpleton responded - how cool is that!)  I'm going to try configuring a 64-bit version of Apache, so I have only 1 Python installation on my machine.  That might take me a while to get right - so I'll respond as soon as I've made progress or hit another roadblock.

Comment: @StefanMusarra: One last thing: You might want to consider using a _different_ server for the WSGI services, if you're worried about having two Apache installations confusing each other (or just confusing you as a human administrator). On the other hand, that would mean you have to learn how to setup, administer, debug, optimize, etc. two different servers, so you might _not_ want to.

Comment: @abarnert: I was planning on returning my ZendServer Apache2.2 to configuring my existing VirtualHosts on port 8000, so I can still run my local PHP web sites (which I debug with Zend Studio - and that plays best with the ZendServer version of Apache2.2).  Then I will install and configure a 64-bit version of Apache to only host my future local Django web sites, say on port 9000.  After that, I need to figure out how to get Eclipse/PyDev to talk to the 64-bit Apache server, but I hope that will be straightforward.  Does that sound right to you?

Comment: @abarnert: And it is kind of lame that the course I'm taking uses Python 2.6.  I will upgrade my machine to Python 2.7.5. when the course ends in a month.  Thanks for the tip on the performance boost (which I just also read on https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/faq/install/)

Comment: @StefanMusarra: That all sounds reasonable.

Comment: @StefanMusarra: Meanwhile, if I were a professor, I probably wouldn't go through the effort of upgrading all the course materials from 2.6 to 2.7; I'd stick with 2.6 until I was ready for 3.x. (Which would have been a few semesters ago, but never mind that…) And for practical purposes, there are still a lot of hosting sites that give you 2.6, and linux distros that come with it in their ESRs.